# Matlab Gui help for signature verification

Tags: matlab

suppose I have created a GUI that lets the user select an image form a location(browsing)and then he clicks the skewness button to calculate the skewness,now when I run the program I select an Image Its Skewness is calculated and stored in a text file,again i browse another Image (but this time I do not run my file i directly click select image button),calculate the skewness but now the skweness of the previous image is overwritten.I want skewness of all the imgs I browse and be saved in the txt file by runing my code just once Please help me 
This is my code:

```
% --- Executes on button press in select_image.
function select_image_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[filename, pathname, filterindex] = uigetfile('*.jpg', 'Pick a .jpg image');
X=([pathname,filename]);
global y;
y=filename;
%display(y);

handles.y=y;
imshow(X);
axes(handles.axes1);



% --- Executes on button press in skewness.
function skewness_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to skewness (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global y;
 I=imread(y);
 I2 = im2double(I);
 s=skewness(I2(:));

 display(s);



fid = fopen('pqfile.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'skewness1=%f',s);
fclose(fid);
% this saves the skweness of the first selected image but when I select an other Images It overwrites the previous value of s.
```

please help me with my doubt.

Comment: May I ask why you are saving as ASCII and why u didn't use `fopen`, `fprintf` and `fclose`?

Comment: K If I use that will I get my desird ouptu? Actually I'm a beginner , that's why I didn't have that idea of fopen

Comment: It is saving the skewness But when I select another Image  and calculate its skweness THE PSKEWNESS OF THE PREVIOUS IMAGE IS OVERWRITTEN. i WANT TO RETAIN THE SKEWNESS OF THE PREVIOUS IMAGE ALSO

Comment: Paste your new code above, please update your question and add that part below of all. Don't update your previous code above.tanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fprintf` instead:

Because you want to save previous data either, you should use `'a'` instead of `'w'` in `fopen`.

```
fid = fopen('pqfile.txt', 'a'); % Write to existing file but append to what is already there
```

Note that you can use `printf` and `printf`, `fprintf` covers writing both to the screen and to a file.

```
fprintf(fid,'skewness1=%f',s);
```

or

```
printf(fid,'skewness1=%f',s);
```

Also don't forget closing the file

```
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: It isn't working   Undefined function or method 'printf' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in ==> MENU>skewness_Callback at 180
printf(fid,'skewness1=%f',s);

Comment: Got it..........:)but everything is coming in 1 line I need my skewnessess to be in order

Comment: just use `%f\n` instead of `%f`